# Can SharePoint Easy-Tabs be wrapped in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I love [Christophe Humbert's Easy Tabs](http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx) for SharePoint. I'm using jQuery on my page layouts and want to add his great code to the `$(document).ready()` function. However, it keeps blowing up with this error:

```
Error: p.innerHTML is undefined
```

And this is on the line with this JS:

```
do {p=p.parentNode;sT=p.innerHTML.split("MSOZoneCell_WebPart");}while (sT.length<4 && p.parentNode.id!="MSO_ContentTable")
```

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#enableEasyTabs').length){
     $(enableEasyTabs);
}
});

/* Easy Tabs v 5.0 * Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Christophe Humbert * http://www.pathtosharepoint.com */
function enableEasyTabs(){
var AP="",sec=0,Header="none",Split="No",Expand="Expand All",Print="Print Preview";
if (document.forms[0].elements["_wikiPageMode.value"]=="true"||document.forms[0].elements["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"].value=="1"){return;}
var el=document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),p=el[el.length-1],sT,a,sep,tabRow;
do {p=p.parentNode;sT=p.innerHTML.split("MSOZoneCell_WebPart");}while (sT.length<4 && p.parentNode.id!="MSO_ContentTable")
if (p.getAttribute("contenteditable")=="true"){return;}
if (p.nodeName=="DIV"){sep=document.createElement("div");p.insertBefore(sep,p.firstChild);tabRow=document.createElement("div");p.insertBefore(tabRow,p.firstChild);}
else{sep=document.createElement("td");var sepTR=document.createElement("tr");sepTR.appendChild(sep);tabRow=document.createElement("td");var tabTR=document.createElement("tr");tabTR.appendChild(tabRow);if (p.nodeName=="TBODY"){p.insertBefore(sepTR,p.firstChild);p.insertBefore(tabTR,p.firstChild);}else if (p.nodeName=="TR"){p.parentNode.insertBefore(tabTR,p);p.parentNode.insertBefore(sepTR,p);}else {return;}}
sep.className="et-separator";tabRow.className="et-tabrow";var children=p.childNodes;p=p.parentNode;var etRoot=[],etHeader=[],etTab=[],tabsID=[];
for (var j=0;j<children.length;j++){try{var d=children[j].getElementsByTagName("td");for (i=0;i<d.length;i++) {if(d[i].id.indexOf("WebPartTitle")==0){var WPid=d[i].id.replace(/WebPartTitle/,"");if (d[i].innerHTML.indexOf("(Hidden)")==-1) {var up=d[i];while (up!=children[j]){if (up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id=WebPart'+WPid+' ')>=0||up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id="WebPart'+WPid+'" ')>=0){WPid="et"+WPid;etHeader[WPid]=up;etRoot[WPid]=children[j];etTab[WPid]=d[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].cloneNode(true);etTab[WPid].id=WPid;etTab[WPid].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";etTab[WPid].onclick=function(){activateTab(this);};tabRow.appendChild(etTab[WPid]);tabsID.push(WPid);break;}up=up.parentNode;}}}}}catch(e){}}
var Tabs=tabRow.getElementsByTagName("span"),TabCount=Tabs.length;
if (Split=="Yes") {var sd=document.createElement("div"),index=Math.floor(TabCount*0.5);tabRow.insertBefore(sd,Tabs[index]);}
if(AP.length && sec>0) {sec=sec*1000;interval="";a=document.createElement("span");a.innerHTML="|>";a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";a.onclick=function(){if(interval==""){this.innerHTML="||";interval=window.setInterval(function(){Autoplay();},sec)}else{this.innerHTML="|>";window.clearInterval(interval);interval=""}};tabRow.appendChild(a);var Autoplay=function(){for(i=0;i<TabCount;i++)if(Tabs[i].className=="et-tab et-activetab"){var j=(i+1)%TabCount;activateTab(Tabs[j]);break}};if (AP=="Play"){a.innerHTML="||";interval=window.setInterval(function(){Autoplay();},sec)};}
if (Expand.length) {a=document.createElement("span");a.innerHTML=Expand;a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";a.onclick=function(){for(i=0;i<tabsID.length;i++){etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";etRoot[tabsID[i]].className=etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/et-offscreen/g,"");etRoot[tabsID[i]].style.pageBreakAfter="always";etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display="";}};tabRow.appendChild(a);}
if (Print.length) {a=document.createElement("span");a.innerHTML=Print;a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";a.onclick=function(){this.style.display="none";var f=document.getElementById("s4-workspace")||document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],ed=p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement(p.nodeName),p);f.appendChild(p);for (j=0;j<f.childNodes.length-1;j++) {try{f.childNodes[j].className+=" et-offscreen";}catch(e){}}a=document.createElement("span");a.innerHTML="Back to Page";a.className="et-tab et-inactivetab";a.onclick=function(){this.previousSibling.style.display="inline-block";this.parentNode.removeChild(this);ed.parentNode.insertBefore(p,ed);ed.parentNode.removeChild(ed);for (j=0;j<f.childNodes.length;j++) {try{f.childNodes[j].className=f.childNodes[j].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g,"");}catch(e){}}};tabRow.appendChild(a);};tabRow.appendChild(a);}
function activateTab(t){document.cookie=tabsID.join("_")+"="+t.id+";path=/";for(i=0;i<tabsID.length;i++){etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display=Header;if(t.id==tabsID[i]){etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-activetab";etRoot[tabsID[i]].className=etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g,"");}else{etTab[tabsID[i]].className="et-tab et-inactivetab";etRoot[tabsID[i]].className+=" et-offscreen";}}}var m=GetCookie(tabsID.join("_"))?GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")):tabsID[0];activateTab(etTab[m]);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the purpose of wrapping the Easy Tabs in jQuery?

You can always combine the Easy Tabs with jQuery - they are both written in the same language, JavaScript.

However, the specific issue here is that you want the Easy Tabs to run after the document is ready, and this is not the correct timing. The way it is written, the script needs to run in the flow of the page, in the context of the Web Part zone where the tabs will be created.

If you wan to run it after the page is ready, you'll need to add a couple steps to find the Web Part zone.

Comment: Thanks, Christophe, for your reply. The reason is this: I have a page layout that will allow users to toggle tabs on/off. Based on the variable, I want to either enable tabs or disable them. I found a way to do this within the flow of the page: I detect if the user wants to enable tabs; if so, I include the script.

Comment: Another question: Is it possible to have the tabs inserted in a specific location? I need it inserted after an H1 tag with ID "page-title". I'm trying to use jQuery to move the tabs but not quite working: All the click events seem to get lost. Thanks.

Comment: In addition to or instead of moving the tabs, try to move the tabs container. As for toggling the tabs, you could enable them but keep them hidden (again via the container) and inactive, until they are toggled on.

Comment: Would the container be the DIVs with the class `et-tabrow` and `et-separator`? I've got a span tag that I try to insert into using `$('#enableEasyTabs').html($(".et-tabrow").html()); $('.et-tabrow').remove();`

Comment: This works: `el = $('.et-tabrow').detach(); el.appendTo('#enableEasyTabs')`.

Comment: Yes, et-tabrow is the container. How about $('.et-tabrow').appendTo('#enableEasyTabs')

Comment: That works too and is only one line :) And here's the server-side code in my page layout, referencing a custom content field called "EnableTabs" which displays as a True/False dropdown for editors: `<%= (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Item["EnableTabs"] == null || Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Item["EnableTabs"].ToString() == "False") ? "" : "<script type='text/javascript' src='../../SiteAssets/js/easytabs-include.js'></script>" %>`

Comment: By the way, I call the jQuery functions in the `$(window).ready()`. By that point in the page load cycle, the `.et-tabrow` object has been created. This won't work with the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Hi, Christophe. Spent much of the day trying to include the JS file in a page layout so users wouldn't have to include it as a CEWP on each page. No luck. It only works correctly if it's a CEWP. Any thoughts?

Comment: The Easy Tabs run within a Web Part zone. If the script is in the page layout, you have to point it to the correct Web Part zone.